# My shipping get a quote is not working in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I want to show shipping price in product view page. In my **view.phtml** The shipping get a quote for shipping price is not working .I have called it by

```
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
```

I have also called the block in catalog.xml by

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```

Any ideas why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- SHOW SHIPPING RATES-->
        <?php $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('ES'); // Set your default shipping country here
        $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
        $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);
        $quote->addProduct($_product);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
        $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();
        // Find cheapest rate
        $cheapestrate = null;
        foreach ($rates as $rate) {
            if (is_null($cheapestrate) || $rate->getPrice() < $cheapestrate) {
                $cheapestrate = $rate->getPrice();
            }
        }
        $corehelper = Mage::helper('core');
        if ($cheapestrate) {
            echo '<p><strong>Shipping costs:</strong> ' . $corehelper->currency($cheapestrate);?></p>
            <?php
            }else {
            echo "<strong>Free shipping</strong> for this product." ;
        }?>
        <!-- END SHOW SHIPPING RATES-->
```

This only works for Simple products

Comment: Shipping cost estimation working on cart page but not working on the checkout page, what is the error?

Comment: @Rathinam you need to elaborate more about the issue maybe create a question about it

Comment: Someone posted the same issue, help @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/216132/57334